# Http live streaming segment number

Tags: http-live-streaming, variant, segment

Using HLS to deliver vod content.
An HLS variants must have the same count of segments between them or the number of segment may vary from variant to variant?

Answer (score 0):

If the variants are the same representation, the segments must be aligned. This is a requirement for adaptive bitrate streaming. So the number of segments cannot vary, and they'll all be the same amount of time.